# Installing a new nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with an Nvidia Gforce 860M and recently found out that you can get the latest Nvidia drivers by using the graphics-drivers ppa. I feel dumb because everytime I've installed Ubuntu I've just used the stand three drivers to choose from and they are outdated. So I added the graphics drivers app to my system and wanted to know how would I install the newest driver? A new list of drivers appears in Additional drivers. I would like to install the 370.23 driver. Do I have to remove my current driver or does it do that automatically when I select that driver?

-Thanks!

Comment: My answer installs the 370.23 drivers, and there is no need to remove the previous drivers.

Comment: Nvidia's website does not recommend 370 for the 860M.

Comment: Please remember to upvote the answer you choose as correct.

Comment: Got it, tryin to get familiar with this forum. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 16.04, the latest driver for the Nvidia 860M is version 367.44.

You should be able to install from Terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```

This should replace your old driver with the new version.

Comment: Do I have to remove the current driver first, or is it safe to just run this command?

Comment: Assuming the ppa is enabled for nvidia drivers, the old driver will be replaced with this code.

Comment: Awesome, I think I'll use the GUI "Additional drivers" to install version 370, I pretty sure it's the same thing as apt-get install .

Comment: Well,didn't expect to get this solved so quickly, the Ubuntu community's fantastic! Thanks a lot you guys!

Answer (score 5):

The following commands are to be run from a terminal window to install the latest (BETA) NVIDIA drivers:

First, set up the graphics-drivers ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Then update and install drivers:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-370
```

---

Hope this helps!