# Stuck in login loop after installing drivers for GTX 1070

Tags: 16.04, nvidia-geforce

I was using GTX 1070 for deep learning with Ubuntu 16.04, while running my program I got error that GPU is out of memory. I reseted my system but now Ubuntu is stuck in a login loop when trying to enter my desktop. When I login, the screen gets black and soon after that the login screen comes back.

However, I tried to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 and it works well. When I install again NVIDIA 1070 driver, I get stuck again in logging loop. The NVIDIA software I install is `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run`.

Comment: Try installing the drivers from the ppa instead of from NVIDIA's site.  The drivers from the PPA are Open Source, so the maintainers of Ubuntu can patch the drivers as needed.  http://askubuntu.com/a/819864/231142

Comment: @Terrance - The Nvidia drivers in that PPA are as proprietary as the ones you obtain by running the Nvidia installer. They do appear in Additional Drivers as "open source" but that doesn't make it so, it's just a mistake. The PPA you linked is mantained by someone who may or may not be an "Ubuntu maintainer" or dev. For all intended purposes it's a third party software repository. That said it's a good suggestion to use that PPA instead of running Nvidia's installer because the drivers there have been tested specifically for Ubuntu.