# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS freezes

Tags: freeze

I'm a new user to ubuntu and linux overall. I've installed clean ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my msi ge60 2oe laptop about a month ago. At the beginning everything was fine except wifi problem but right now my system freezes almost every 30 minutes. I've made some research online and found that there are others troubled by this problem. Here are the links related to problem :

[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS freezing about every 10-15 seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230930/ubuntu-20-04-lts-freezing-about-every-10-15-seconds)

[Ubuntu 20.04 freezing and crashing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297692/ubuntu-20-04-freezing-and-crashing)

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/ga2onc/ubuntu_2004_randomly_freezing/

There were some suggestions like changing the NVIDIA driver settings etc. but It still freezes. Is there anything that I can do about it? I'm on my thesis year and compiling my code takes really long time (~8 hours). If it helps here are some properties of my laptop :

product:    GE60 2OC\2OE (To be filled by O.E.M.)

product:    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz

size:   3290MHz

capacity:   3800MHz

description:    3D controller

product:    GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M]

vendor: NVIDIA Corporation

description:    VGA compatible controller

product:    4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics
Controller

vendor: Intel Corporation

To be precise, freezing starts with increasing CPU usage and minor lags like my mouse cursor is not moving properly and sites are not working properly. Then It freezes for good, I can't move my mouse and only solution is to use Alt + PrtScn + REISUB.
Also couple of days ago, while I was running my code, system gave crash report but It didn't effect my work. I'm not sure it is related but I'll share it just in case :

> total 1104
> -rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops         whoopsie   2546 Ara  8 16:53 linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic.177487.crash
> -rw-r----- 1 kernoops         whoopsie   2554 Ara  8 13:07 linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic.179685.crash
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root             whoopsie      0 Ara  8 13:33 linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic.179685.upload
> -rw------- 1 whoopsie         whoopsie     37 Ara  8 13:33 linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic.179685.uploaded
> -rw-r----- 1 kernoops         whoopsie   2557 Ara  8 13:32 linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic.179865.crash
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root             whoopsie      0 Ara  8 13:36 linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic.179865.upload
> -rw------- 1 whoopsie         whoopsie     37 Ara  8 13:36 linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic.179865.uploaded
> -rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops         whoopsie   2597 Ara  8 13:40 linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic.183486.crash
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-timesync whoopsie 317988 Ara  8 16:53 _usr_lib_systemd_systemd-timesyncd.102.crash
> -rw-r----- 1 root             whoopsie 786075 Ara  8 16:53 _usr_lib_systemd_systemd-udevd.0.crash

Comment: During boot, try selecting an older kernel in the Advanced Options.  Try selecting the 5.4.0-54 kernel.  How did you setup your NVIDIA drivers?  Did you use the graphics-drivers PPA?  Add these to your question.  But, for now I really do recommend using the older kernel if it is still installed until you get your thesis done.

Comment: Hi! I'm using proprietary, tested version of NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-390. I also checked my old kernel and I have 5.4.0-56-generic, is it okay to use this version or should I find 5.4.0-54 kernel version? Since I'm a newbie to linux, I'm a bit nervous about installing something wrong.

Comment: I would recommend removing the NVIDIA driver that you installed on your system.  I think it is done by running `sudo ./NVIDIAdrivernamefileyoudownloaded --uninstall` or `--remove`, it's been so long for me since I have used their driver I don't remember.  Then in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/819864/231142 you can install the `nvidia-driver-455` which should work fine with your video card.  Plus, using the driver from the PPA carries over when you get a new kernel update.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm on it! I'll reply the changes.

Comment: Hello again! I've changed my nvidia driver as you said and It's been almost 5 hours without any freezing/crush. I think this solved my problem! Thank you so much sir! Before I close the thread, I would like to ask you one last question. Is it good behavior to use on-demand option in nvidia-settings or should I leave always on performance mode(NVIDIA)?

Comment: Performance mode means that it is always ready to go where on demand means when you launch 3d apps or things that will need the high performance.  It might cause a little bit of a slow down, but I leave mine at on demand and it seems to be fine.  Plus, the card stays cooler with on demand and the fan is not running high speed all the time.  Also, on demand would be better on your battery.

Comment: Alright! Thank you so much again! I've resolved my problem.